# How would I write this in CoffeeScript?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, waitforimages

I'm having trouble with CoffeeScript in my first Rails application. I'm using the [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) jQuery plugin, which is saved in a separate file called `waitforimages.jquery.js`. Rails automatically created `home.js.coffee`, in which I'd like to include the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('#fullbleed').waitForImages(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(3000);
});
```

But how would I write this using CoffeeScript notation?

**UPDATE**

Things are working great now, so I thought I would post my final code. One of the issues was that I wasn't loading the `waitForImages` plugin *before* home.js.coffee.

CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).ready -> $('#fullbleed').waitForImages -> $(@).fadeIn 3000
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery.waitforimages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To answer any "how would I write this in CoffeeScript?" question, I would recommend js2coffee.org.

Comment: That's a cool resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `-> ...` instead of `function(){ ... }`. Optionally, you can also swap `this` with `@`.

```
$('#fullbleed').waitForImages ->
    $(@).fadeIn(3000)
```

If you really like to save characters, then you can also omit the last two parentheses, and get:

```
$('#fullbleed').waitForImages -> $(@).fadeIn 3000
```

Comment: Wow, that's very compact. However, I'm getting an 'undefined' error. It doesn't seem to recognize the waitForImages function (even though it's properly linked).

Comment: @David Did you correctly load your `waitForImages` jQuery plugin? Keep in mind that you have to load a jQuery plugin *after* jQuery itself.

Comment: @David Could you update the question and show a demo where the problem shows up? Here's a basic example which shows that the code works: http://jsfiddle.net/B47LG/

Comment: Yes, if I place the `waitForImages` function in the same file, then there's no problem. I guess my question is really about how to use functions from different files...

Comment: @David The placement of the code does not matter. What matters is that the order of loading is something like `jquery.js` > `jquery.waitForImages.js` > `code-from-answer.js`. Do you have a link to the source code of your app?

Comment: Okay, I updated my post with my source code. Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: @David Load `home.js` **after** `jquery.waitforimages.js`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the very useful http://js2coffee.org:

```
$("#fullbleed").waitForImages ->
  $(this).fadeIn 3000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#fullbleed').waitForImages ->
  $(@).fadeIn 3000
```

or even:

```
$('#fullbleed').waitForImages ->$(@).fadeIn 3000
```